# Работа с картами

Tags: google-maps-api, карты, яндекс-карты, 2gis-api

Есть ли возможность получить геометрию здания по карте через APi? Вопрос не к конкретной карте (яндекс, гугл, 2гис), а в целом. Мне необходимо получить укрупненные габариты большого количества зданий для дальнейших манипуляций с ними.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете это делать с использование Google Maps API следующим образом:

Создайте карту Гугл с гео-координатами вашего объекта + выберите тип карты как hybrid + установите приближение (zoom) на максимально возможное.

Пример:

```html
<body>
<main>
<header>
<h1 id=name property=name>Stockholm Palace</h1>
</header>
<div role=application>
<div>
<div id=map></div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
<script>function initMap(){new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{zoom:18,center:{lat:59.326822,lng:18.071719},mapTypeId:"hybrid",mapTypeControl:!1})};</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Ваш ключ&amp;language=en&amp;callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
```